C++23: do we need to #include types of default arguments?
#include <memory>

struct A;

struct B {
    B(int){}
    B(std::unique_ptr<A> = nullptr);
};

int main(int, char**) {
    B b{1};
}

This code does not compile with msvc v19.38 and /std:c++latest, with the following message: error C2027: use of undefined type 'A'.
But it compiles with /std:c++20, and also compiles with gcc -std=c++23.
Do you know what the standard says? Do we need to #incude "A.h" to compile this code? Note that if we remove = nullptr it compiles well.
Compiler Explorer links:

MSVC c++latest: https://godbolt.org/z/qYTKMWGof KO
MSVC c++20: https://godbolt.org/z/z7M7TqEac OK
GCC c++23: https://godbolt.org/z/hd89Ebe9W OK
Conformance Viewer: https://godbolt.org/z/qP148erWE


why do you think it matters that its a default argument? Doesnt  B(std::unique_ptr<A>); have the same error?

Dupes: When does unique_ptr require a complete type? and What are the rules for standard library containers and incomplete types? and Is std::unique_ptr required to know the full definition of T?

...no it does not https://godbolt.org/z/vbKrdrPhh ;)

@463035818_is_not_an_ai "Note that if we remove = nullptr it compiles well"

I suggest reporting a bug to https://github.com/microsoft/STL

See this answer in the Is std::unique_ptr required to know the full definition of T?. So another msvc bug.

https://godbolt.org/z/qP148erWE

@user12002570 I really think it's not a duplicate. From my perspective we do not need to #include "A.h" here, since the 2nd constructor of B is not defined and not called.

@Thibaud That's what the dupe explains. That the program is well-formed and you should file a bug for msvc. MSVC has many such bugs(too many to mention here).

I posted https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Forward-declaration-of-default-argument-/10636745 which is a duplicate of https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Regression-MSVC-1933-with-unqiue_ptr-if/10514504 --> it's not a bug, compiler and STL are following the Standard.
